# In-Between Target function for Shape Keys?

Tags: animation, rigging

It would greatly improve Blender’s character rigging (and animation) capabilities if the Shape Keys tool is updated with an In-Between Target function (see existing example from Maya below).

[In-Between Target function for Shape Keys - Video](https://vimeo.com/733962816)

Currently our best option is to work-around the missing function using New Shape From Mix supported by carefully ordered driver keys.

Does anyone have any better solutions for this?

Thank you
Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to my question on Right Click Select, Asian3D made me aware of this Add On by NevilArt

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=De3fiWcQnpA&t=44s
https://github.com/NevilArt/BsMax

It’s an extremely useful solution for my blinks challenge and hopefully will inspire the Blender Gods into implementing something in their future releases.